# Access query: find highest rank product in each category

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a query that calculates product rank per Category:

```
qryEvalProd    
category Product   Rank
-------- -------   ----
Cat1     Prod6     1254
Cat1     Prod1      950
Cat1     Prod2      800
Cat2     Prod3     1500
Cat2     Prod5      950
```

I want to make a query on that, to return the best product for each category:

```
category Product   
-------- -------   
Cat1     Prod6     
Cat2     Prod3
```

I know I could do that using a correlated subquery containing a group by and Max, however but for performance reason I am trying to make it in one shot using Group By and First. But I can't express the fact I want the First Prod of each cat sorted by DESC Rank.

Is there a way to do that in one pass ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tweak lets you add the ORDER you wanted.  It uses a subquery...but not a *correlated* subquery, so performance is not impaired:

```
SELECT Category, First(Product) AS BestProduct
FROM (
  SELECT Category, Product, Rank
  FROM qryEvalProd
  ORDER BY Category, Rank DESC
) AS Ordered
GROUP BY Category;
```

Comment: Hey, that looks VERY interesting, testing tomorrow first time (I'm in Europe and it's the evening now)... I'll keep you updated.

Comment: Brilliant. I separated it in two distinct queries for maintenability (my question was very simplified for SO), but this is really fast and efficient. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the use of the [HAVING clause](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/having-clause-HP001032238.aspx) may help?

Comment: Perhaps... but how ?  That's the question :-)

Answer (score 0):

In fact this seems to work. I am just a bit annoyed because I can't force in my statement  the order of the input dataset, but anyway, it wors..

```
SELECT Category, First(Product) AS BestProduct
FROM qryEvalProd    
GROUP BY Category;
```

I can add `ORDER BY Category` without any impact on the output. I would have liked to add `ORDER BY Category, Rank` to be sure, but that's not accepted.

If someone has a better suggestion you're still welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You might start with something like this:

```
SELECT Category, Product
FROM qryEvalProd
WHERE Product = 
    (SELECT TOP 1 Self.Product 
    FROM qryEvalProd AS Self
    WHERE Self.Category = qryEvalProd.Category
    ORDER BY Self.Rank DESC)
```

If there is the possibility of ties (that is, two products in the same category with the same rank), this query will arbitrarily pick one of them.

If you want it to always pick the same one, you can probably make it do what you want by changing the the ORDER BY clause.  For example, if in the event of a tie, you want it to pick the one with the first Product value in alphabetical order, you might change the ORDER BY clause to:

```
ORDER BY Self.Rank DESC, Self.Product
```

If you want it instead to list all the products with the highest rank, you might use a query like this:

```
SELECT Category, Product
FROM qryEvalProd
WHERE Rank = 
    (SELECT Max(Self.Rank) 
    FROM qryEvalProd AS Self
    WHERE Self.Category = qryEvalProd.Category)
```

Comment: Brian, thanks for that elaborate answer. At first I was wanting to reject it without a try, as my question specifically mentions that I want to avoid  correlated subqueries. I decided to give it a try anyway, and oh surprise, the query opened up nearly twice as fast as with my solution. But then....once you start scrolling down, it takes several minutes every time I press PgDn. Unusable. My solution took 6 minutes to execute and then no additional delay from page to page. I must say the volumes are relatively high: 65000 Access rows filtered out 360000,  combined with 100000 Oracle rows.

Comment: @iDevelop, sorry I didn't see the "no correlated subqueries" condition. A way to do it without a correlated subquery would be: 

1. Write a query that find the maximum rank for each category, like: `SELECT Category, Max(Rank) AS Rank FROM qryEvalProd`

2. Join this query with your original one on both Category and Rank.

This will return multiple records for each category in the event of a tie.  Post back if that is not what you want.

I don't believe that you can do it "in one shot".

Comment: @iDevelop, by "your original one" I meant qryEvalProd.

Comment: @iDevelop, the query you posted `SELECT Category, First(Product) AS BestProduct FROM qryEvalProd GROUP BY Category;` won't necessarily work because you can't control the order in which the data is processed, and as a result, which records get picked by "First".  To illustrate:  1.  Create a new table with the sample data in your original post, except enter it in ascending order of Rank by Category, and, 2.  Run the query you posted.  It will not return the correct results, even if you sort in a separate query first.  I'd put this comment on your "answer" thread, but can't for some reason.